# Does Intellij 15.0.3 support gradle and scala?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm using Intellij IDEA 15.0.3 BUILD#IC-143.1821 with

- Scala plugin 2.1.0
- Gradle plugin 143.1821.5

When I load a gradle project, I found I could not run scala application with this error:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7535 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/cloudera/apps/intellij/idea-IC-143.1184.17/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/home/cloudera/workplace/spark-streaming-test/out/production/spark-streaming-test:/home/cloudera/.m2/repository/com/github/scopt/scopt_2.10/3.3.0/scopt_2.10-3.3.0.jar:/home/cloudera/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/scala-logging/scala-logging-api_2.10/2.1.2/scala-logging-api_2.10-2.1.2.jar:/home/cloudera/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/scala-logging/scala-logging-slf4j_2.10/2.1.2/scala-logging-slf4j_2.10-2.1.2.jar:/home/cloudera/apps/intellij/idea-IC-143.1184.17/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain HelloWorld
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Predef$
    at HelloWorld$.main(HelloWorld.scala:7)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Predef$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 7 more
```

Obviously scala libraries are not in the classpath.

- In "Open Module Settings", I can find the scala libraries in "Project
  settings -> Modules -> Dependencies".
- in "Project settings -> Libraries", there is scala-sdk using 2.10.4.
- Nothing in "project settings -> Facets"

IDEA seems not support Gradle and Scala. If I create a new project, select Gradle, I can only use framework Java, Groovy and Kotlin ; while select scala, only Scala, SBT and Activator.

I'm new to Intellij. Did I make some mistakes?

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-downloading the scala sdk in your global settings?  If it got deleted for some reason, IntelliJ isn't very good at detecting that, and it will just blindly continue to try using a nonexistent file. (I haven't use 15.X, but that's how it is in 14.X)

Comment: Your suggestion helped me to find out what is wrong. My gradle job add apache spark as "provided" dependency using nebula provied-base plugin, the scala libraries are transitive dependencies. They (the provided jars) are not in the classpath if I run a scala application in Intellij. If I manually put the scala libraries (scala-library and scala-reflect) in "Open Module Settings -> Project Settings -> Modules -> Libraries -> Scala library", I can run a simple Scala application in Intellij. I still need to find a solution to run an application with provided dependencies.

Comment: I found this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107048. It is exactly the same problem I face. Look like I have to stay away of Intellij until jetBrains fixes it (it was requested for two years ago.)